# Move to next message

Tags: emacs, gnus

I have a messages line this:

```
message 1
  answer 1.1
     answer 1.1.1
  answer 1.2
  answer 1.3
massage 2
...
```

and I have the line in my .gnus.el:

```
(global-set-key [f9] (lambda () (interactive) (gnus-summary-lower-score-by-subj-substr-temp)))
```

When I select "message 1" and press F9 next lines:

- message1
- answer 1.1
- answer 1.1.1
- answer 1.2
- answer 1.3

change the score.

But I need the selection move to next message (message 2) when I press F9. How can I get it?

Answer (score 1):

I have found a solution:

```
(global-set-key [f9] 
(lambda () 
  (interactive) 
  (gnus-summary-lower-score-by-subj-substr-temp)
  (gnus-summary-next-thread 1)))  ;; lower by subject
```